# Use \( & \) instead of \left( & \right) in align to make parenthesis

Tags: align, sharelatex, parenthesis

I would like to use  `\(` & `\)` instead of `\left(` & `\right)` to make parenthesis adjust size in align. My problem is that `\(` & `\)` is already defined as a way to 'start math mode'. So the following is giving me a problem:

```
\renewcommand{\(}{\left (}
\renewcommand{\)}{\right )}
```

When I use the editor in ShareLaTex this using `\(` & `\)` in an equation gives me an error: `open inline math \( used inside existing mathmode \begin{align}`.
The following document will compile but give this error and mark my equation red:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\renewcommand{\(}{\left (}
\renewcommand{\)}{\right )}
\begin{document}

\begin{align}
    \frac{1}{2}=\(\frac{1}{4}\)^{\(\frac{1}{2}\)}
\end{align}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1436) It works, the red outline you see is just Sharelatex's parser fooled by your `\renewcommand`. Most parsers can't keep track of definitions done in the document and won't "understand" your new syntax, then `\(...\)` is still a math-mode shift for the parser. This follows the rule "Only TeX can parse TeX."

Comment: I also did that for a long time, many years ago, but it is definitely a bad practice.

Comment: `\left(` is useful for items of variable size such as matrices, but for items of known size it is almost always better to use `(` or `\bigl(` or one of the other named sizes, so a shortcut for `\left(` should not be needed very often.